# Wagtail: How can I copy a page instance in wagtail with all its property and method

Tags: python, django-models, wagtail

I have a CoursePage model in Wagtail site.

```
class CoursePage(Page):
    .....
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute)
    .....
```

I have a django models ForeignKey field in it named *institute*

I want to make a copy of its instance programmatically so that the newly created instance **institute** field can be modified.

I tried django approach of copying model instance, that is:

```
course = CoursePage.objects.all()[0]
course.pk = None
course.save()
```

But it doesnot work out.
It only works with the model inherited with django *models.Model*. but not with the model inherited with **Page**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Page` model implements a `copy` method to do this:

```
def copy(self, recursive=False, to=None, update_attrs=None,
         copy_revisions=True, keep_live=True, user=None):
```

The parameters it accepts are:

- `recursive` - if true, copies child pages as well
- `to` - the page to create the new copy under (defaults to creating a sibling of the existing page)
- `update_attrs` - a dict of fields to update while copying, such as `{'institute': other_institute}`
- `copy_revisions` - whether to copy revision history
- `keep_live` - whether to copy the 'live' status
- `user` - the owner of the new page, for permission purposes